# Get the sum of a count over a group per id

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, count, pivot

I have a dataset where different schools run the same course over different years. I needed to get the total number of courses each school ran for each year. I did this with the following query.

```
SELECT s.school_id
     , s.name school_name
     , year(c.start_date) as the_year
     , COUNT(*) as total
  FROM course c 
  LEFT 
  JOIN school s 
    ON c.school_id = s.school_id
 group 
    by c.school_id
     , the_year 
 ORDER 
    BY the_year;
```

Which works fine, However, I also need to get the total number of courses each school has ran over the earliest to the latest recorded year of the table. The table I would eventually print would look something like this

```
School | 2018 | 2019 | 2020 | Total
-----------------------------------
ACME   | 0    | 2    | 0    | 2
Aca    | 2    | 0    | 1    | 3
```

I could make this table with the previous query, except for the Total column.

*Example output*

```
school_id | school_name | the_year | total 
------------------------------------------
3         | Aca         | 2018     | 2
7         | ACME        | 2019     | 2
7         | Aca         | 2020     | 1
```

How could I query the database to get a dataset for the total, so I can append it to my output table? Thanks.

Comment: *I could make this table with the previous query* Show.

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code, and see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: You haven't explained how you were able to generate the expected output 'except for the total column'.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    s.name as school_name, 
    sum(year(c.start_date) = 2018) cnt_2018,
    sum(year(c.start_date) = 2019) cnt_2019,
    sum(year(c.start_date) = 2020) cnt_2020,
    count(*) as total
from course c 
inner join school s on c.school_id = s.school_id
group by s.school_id, s.name
order by s.name
```

Notes:

- your original query is ambiguous about which table column `start_date` comes from; based on your explanation, I assumed `course`
- I don't think a `left join` is really needed, so I changed that to `inner join`
- I might be a little more efficient to express the conditional expressions with half-open intervals, like: `sum(c.start_date >= '2018-01-01' and c.start_date < '2019-01-01') cnt_2018`

Comment: `s.school_id` in GROUP BY seems to be excess. `s.name` in ORDER BY is not logically safe - using output column alias instead seems to be more correct.

Comment: @Akina: *s.school_id in GROUP BY seems to be excess*: what if two different shools have the same name? *s.name in ORDER BY is not logically safe*: sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @GMB  *what if two different shools have the same name?* They will be non-distinguisheable in the output. *I don't understand what you mean.* I mean that it is correct inn this particular case, but while using as a pattern one may create incorrect query when the source column used in ordering expression is not included in grouping expression.